The boundary of p-value regarding the hypothesis testing of discrete distribution
Q: $X\sim B(1, p),\sum X \sim (5, p) = 4, H_0: p = 0.5, H_1: p \ne 0.5$
A: Since the mean of sum of X is $\frac52$, p-value is $P(\sum X\ge 4) + P(\sum X \le 4 - 2 \times \frac3 2=1) = ...$
My question is: why $\ge $ rather than $>$. I know that p-value means the probability of refusing $H_0$ while true, but what's the meaning of refusing $H_0$ when the testing statistic($\sum X$) equals to of samples?

The $p$-value is the conditional probability of obtaining a test statistic at least as extreme as the one that was observed, assuming the null hypothesis is true.  There are discussions about what "at least as extreme" actually means (especially in the context of a two-tailed test), but in the binomial/Bernoulli case, there is no dispute:  "at least as extreme" means that the probability of such an outcome is at least as small or smaller than the probability of the outcome that was observed.
Moreover, there is no ambiguity as to whether the boundary point is included in the $p$-value calculation:  it is included, because it represents what was observed.
That said, I would not have used the reasoning that you showed for the computation of the $p$-value.  Rather, we would calculate a table of probabilities under $H_0$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c}
x & \Pr[X = x \mid H_0] \\
\hline
0 & \binom{5}{0} (1/2)^0 (1 - 1/2)^{5-0} = \frac{1}{32} \\
1 & \binom{5}{1} (1/2)^1 (1 - 1/2)^{5-1} = \frac{5}{32} \\
2 & \frac{10}{32} \\
3 & \frac{10}{32} \\
4 & \frac{5}{32} \\
5 & \frac{1}{32}
\end{array}$$
Then the $p$-value is the sum of all probabilities in the table that are less than or equal to that corresponding to the outcome that was observed, which in this case is $\Pr[X = 4 \mid H_0] = \frac{5}{32}$.  This gives us
$$p = \frac{1}{32} + \frac{5}{32} + \frac{5}{32} + \frac{1}{32} = \frac{12}{32} = 0.375.$$
While this gives the same answer as in your computation, the reasoning is different, because we are not calculating the mean and using it to compute the probability for the opposite tail of the test.  Rather, we are applying the $p$-value definition in a more direct way.

You mean "no dispute" in this two-sided case of one-sample Binomial problem. Is it due the specific $H_0:p=0.5$? If we test $p=0.3$, I think there is still dispute.

Thanks for your reply. From my perspective, the p-value of a two-tailed test means $P(T \le mean-|t||H_0) + P(T \ge mean+|t| | H_0)$, where $T$ means the testing statistic. Is that right? Could I have a common equation about solving the p-value problems for all continuous/discrete one-tailed/two-tailed? Besides, what's the reason behind your solution? What's the meaning of "all the probabilities $\le$ P(X=4)" in this case?
